# Динамическое подключение класса

Tags: python

Мне необходимо подключить класс, причем имя файла и класс указать переменной.

```
from переменная import переменная
```

Comment: Может, exec() или eval() ? Лучше, поподробней напишите

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
module = __import__('module_name') # Импортируем модуль module_name
A = getattr(module, 'A') # Получаем класс A из модуля
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно совсем тупо

```
imp = 'from %s import %s' % (module_name,  class_name)
exec (imp)
```